# Zebra 105SL Plus printing wrong UPC

Tags: windows-xp, printing, barcode, zebra-printer

We have a Zebra 105SL Plus for the labels of our products. And we have a major issue concerning our UPC printing, sometimes the printed label would have a modified barcode than the one that was designed in Label Matrix, although the UPC number is right the barcode isn't and although it doesn't happen often, its a huge pain to realize our warehouse returned the product cause of wrong codes and it just delays the whole process of getting it to our costumers. I've been looking around for solutions online with no success, re-calibrated the printer, re-installed the software. And the issue persists, any leads as to the possible reasoning behind this would be greatly appreciated.

We design one single label in our software which then proceeds to print in a 3-column label roll. When this error happens it usually happens along a whole column, could be any of the three columns this roll has.

I attach an image with 2 codes from the same batch for reference.

[image]
[image]

You can see how although the same UPC number the barcode is different.

The event hasn't repeated (Thankfully) but I would hate to face this issue again in the future without knowing what's causing it. I have added better quality images.

Comment: How is the printer connected? USB, Serial, Parallel, Network...?

Comment: Parallel port @CanadianLuke

Comment: Is it working from another computer as well?

Comment: No, there's only one system connected to this printer @CanadianLuke

Comment: I'm very familiar with this printer but unfortunately am not at all familiar with the software you mention, Label Matrix. However, the true string that should be represented by the human readable in your second picture is `7501940556303`. Are you sure that the human readable text truly represents the data in the barcode?

Comment: I should mention, you are only experiencing a change in the 7th character, since the last is a check digit and is calculated based on the preceding characters. If you are manually typing in the UPC number, you may just have a typo.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking @root , the barcode doesn't represent the numbers beneath it. Codes are scanned upon departure from our packing warehouse and arrival at the storage facility

Comment: What is the process for creating the barcodes in Label Matrix? Is Someone manually typing in the UPC and printing (eg) 100 labels? Are you sure that the human readable is actually representing the data from the barcode? It is possible that there is no link between the two.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Zebra printers do not use a "font" for printing barcodes. Instead, the barcode printing is all built into the printer. Your software simply sends a command to the printer that says "print barcode type x size y at position z" and the printer does all the hard work. The barcode has to be printed so the bars are in vertical position, or problems may occur.

The [latest Zebra drivers and firmware](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/industrial/105sl.html#downloadlistitem_cd8) date from 2014,
so are not being updated any more.

You might have better luck with the
[Zebra Windows Printer Drivers by Seagull](http://www.seagullscientific.com/drivers/zebra-windows-printer-drivers)
which date from this year and are being updated regularly.
The Seagull website also contains much information which can be useful.

See also [Resolving Print Quality Issues](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8309&actp=RSS), just in case this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it may be a port setting. Check the manual for your printer for what it requires for the Parallel Port. In Windows XP, you can click on **Start**, right-click on **My Computer**, click **Manage**. On the left hand side, click on *Device Manager*. On the right hand side, expand **Ports**, and double-click on the LPT port that appears. Check that the second tab contains the same settings as the printer manufacturer recommends.

Next, check that the same settings are in the application you are printing from. Because each application is different, you will need to explore the menus until you can find the Printer Setup or Printer Settings option, somewhere.

If this still does not work, next step would be a new printer cable, or a new printer.

Comment: Does it make any difference if I mention this machine is running win XP SP2?

Comment: @JustDoIt Updated the answer. Same principal, check that the port is communicating how the manufacturer expects it to.

Answer (score 0):

Zebra printers do allow you to use custom fonts which can be loaded into the devices firmware.  As far as what harrymc pointed out "print barcode type x size y at position z" this language that's used to communicate with zebra printers is called ZPL / EPL. He does make some good points and the language is literally as easy as what I quote him saying.

Having experience with Zebra printers and Retail Sales Systems and designing my own UPC label software. There could be a couple reasons which could be causing this issue to occur. I highly doubt it's calibration related though but i'm not ruling that out.

In your screenshot you have SKU's that define product within your current point of sale. SKU'S are usually used as UPCs as well when printing labels which allow you to relate your UPC  (SKU) with an item within your system. In this case in the screenshots, Is it possible that you are printing the vendor UPC(s) for the actual SKU of your product instead of the SKU (label template with one text field as SKU and barcode field as VendorUPC?) **You may have product in your system with multiple vendor upcs**. The UPC's look rather similiar which leads me to believe this may be the issue.

Hope you find this post useful.

Answer (score 0):

> the barcode doesn't represent the numbers beneath it.

There may be no link in your label file between the data in the barcode and the human readable output below it. It is possible to incorrectly design a label who's human readable output does not actually represent the actual data in the barcode.

In both of the images you posted, the human readable reads `7501945556308`, but the data in the barcode of the second image actually represents `7501940556303`. The 7th digit should be `5` and instead is `0`. Since this string is clearly a UPC, the last digit also changes because it is a [check digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_digit) - a character that is calculated based on the preceding 12 digits.

I highly doubt this is a printer problem. You should confirm that the human readable is actually linked to (and is representing) the data in the barcode and not an unrelated text object. You should also remove as many human-input related elements on the label as possible to reduce error and ease automation.

Comment: So even if there's only one single label design, there's still a chance of different outputs?

Comment: @JustDoIt The point is that the output is based on the design of the label. The best label file to print this without error is to have a barcode that is hard coded to produce `7501945556308` that has a human readable linked to the barcode. There are many other ways to setup your label, most of which could produce an error. Why don't we clear some stuff up in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access